# Enviar dados para banco de dados

Tags: java, jdbc

Estou estudando pra uma prova de java sobre banco de dados e estou bem confuso, eu estava fazendo um programa com base em outro, fiz uma tela de cadastro e funciona perfeito, a unica coisa que falta é enviar  e eu não sei como fazer isso olho o exemplo e não consigo achar.

### Código que Cadastra:

```
 Produtos t = new Produtos();

 try
 {
    t.setMarca(txtMarca.getText());

    t.setNome(txtNome.getText());
    t.setPreco(Float.parseFloat(txtPreco.getText()));
    t.setQuantia(Integer.parseInt(txtQuantidade.getText()));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Sucesso a cadastrar", 
            "Sucesso" ,JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);       
    Limpar();
}
catch(Exception ex){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Erro a cadastrar", 
            "Erro" ,JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);               
}
```

Eu tenho um método salvar mas não entendo ele e se esta certo ou não

```
public void Salvar() throws SQLException
{ 
    try
    {
        conectaBanco conexao = new conectaBanco();
        String sql = ("insert into produtos (nome,marca,preco,quantia) values (?,?,?,?) ");
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = conexao.prepareStatement(sql)) {
           stmt.setString(1, nome);
           stmt.setString(2,marca);
           stmt.setFloat(3, preco);
           stmt.setInt(4, quantia);
           conexao.desconecta();
           stmt.execute();
        }
    }           
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
         System.out.println("Erro");
    }  
 }
```

Comment: Olá Carlos, bem vindo ao Stack Overflow. A sua dúvida não ficou muito clara para mim mesmo lendo o código. Com o que extamente você está tendo dificuldade? Seu código de cadastro está razoavelmente ok. No método ´salvar´ eu moveria esse `desconecta` para uma cláusula `finally`. Também vale a pena atentar para as convenções de código do Java (Classes começam com letra maiúscula, métodos com letra minúsculas), bem como orientação a objetos e *design* limpo (e.g., eu receberia um `Produto produto` como parâmetro do método salvar ao invés de alimentar a classe diretamente, e trataria as exceções).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muda o método Salvar para a forma abaixo, pois tem um simples erro onde você está desconectado do banco de dados antes de fazer a execução do insert no mesmo:

```
public void Salvar() throws SQLException
{ 
    try
    {
        conectaBanco conexao = new conectaBanco();
        String sql = ("insert into produtos (nome,marca,preco,quantia) values (?,?,?,?) ");
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = conexao.prepareStatement(sql)) {
           stmt.setString(1, nome);
           stmt.setString(2,marca);
           stmt.setFloat(3, preco);
           stmt.setInt(4, quantia);
           stmt.execute();
           conexao.desconecta();
        } catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Erro insert.");
        }// finally { //Ou você pode desconectar usando o finally do try
            //conexao.desconecta();
        //}

    }           
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
         System.out.println("Erro");
    }  
 }
```